# setting value on a datePicker from int/string

Tags: android, datepicker

I have the following function:

```
public String splitDate(String data, int i){
        String[] items = data.split("/");
        for(String item:items){
            return items[i];
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Which takes a `date string` like this "12/24/2013" and splits it.

Using this function I am trying to instantiate my datePicker in that particular order:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int yy = 0;
    int dd = 0;
    int mm = 0;
if(dateString.length()>1){
    yy = Integer.parseInt(splitDate(dateString,2);
    dd = Integer.parseInt(splitDate(dateString,1);
    mm  = Integer.parseInt(splitDate(dateString,0);
}else{
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
}
```

But using this function I get the following error:

```
08-27 00:14:39.383: E/AndroidRuntime(16368): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 00:14:39.383: E/AndroidRuntime(16368): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: current should be >= start and <= end
```

Somebody help ? How do I get the `String dateString` to populate the date picker ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use simple date format to get the information from your string, here is a simple function that can parse your date and return the required field:

```
private int getFromCalendar(String strDate,int field)
{
    int result = -1;
    try
    {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");// this is your date format "12/24/2013" = "MM/dd/yyy"
        java.util.Date date = formatter.parse(strDate);//convert to date
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();// get calendar instance
        cal.setTime(date);//set the calendar date to your date
        result = cal.get(field); // get the required field  
        return result;//return the result.
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

and this is how you make the call:

```
int yy = getFromCalendar("12/24/2013",Calendar.YEAR);
int mm = getFromCalendar("12/24/2013",Calendar.MONTH);
int dd = getFromCalendar("12/24/2013",Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```